# How i can implement bottomSheet in jetpack compose with three states?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I need to implement this three states bottom sheet layout with jetpack compose usage, how i can implement this by best practices?

[image: bottom sheet states]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

`ModalBottomSheetValue` has a state `HalfExpanded`

> The bottom sheet is partially visible at 50% of the screen height.
> This state is only enabled if the height of the bottom sheet is more
> than 50% of the screen height.

as a result yours `ModalBottomSheetLayout` should have a height of more than half of the screen

My example. Please pay attention to this code `height(600.dp)`. Try to play with this value

```
class ComposeActivity7 : ComponentActivity() {

    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeTutorialTheme {
                val modalBottomSheetState =
                    rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                Scaffold(
                    floatingActionButton = {
                        FloatingActionButton(
                            onClick = {
                                scope.launch {
                                    modalBottomSheetState.show()
                                }
                            }) {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Rounded.Add,
                                contentDescription = "add"
                            )
                        }
                    }) {
                    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
                        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
                        sheetContent = {
                            MySheet()

                        }
                    ) {
                        Text("hello")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MySheet() {
    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(600.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: How did you achieve it? I tried your code and tones of other options it is not possible to swipe to increase height :(